# cURL with SSL return me verify locations

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I try to make a cURL Authentication, but I have problems with the SSL certificates.

I have this code:

```
$username = "123";
$password = "123";
$host = "https://api.shipnow.com.ar/users/authentication";

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$username:$password") // <---
);

$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAPATH, '/cacert.pem');
$return = curl_exec($process);
$error = curl_error($process);
curl_close($process);

var_dump($error);
```

But return me this:

> error setting certificate verify locations:
>     CAfile: /cacert.pem
>     CApath: /cacert.pem

I download the cacert.pem from this link:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

And I put it in my project folder, next to index.php

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Regards,

Comment: What are you trying to acomplisth with that certificate? Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe file is not exists. Can you try this code and check file.

```
$username = "123";
$password = "123";
$host = "https://api.shipnow.com.ar/users/authentication";

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$username:$password") // <---
);

// Check File
if(!file_exists('/cacert.pem')) die('File not exists.');

$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAPATH, '/cacert.pem');
$return = curl_exec($process);
$error = curl_error($process);
curl_close($process);

var_dump($error);
```

Comment: hi, yes, this return me that the file don't exist. Where i need put this file?

Comment: Replace file name `/cacert.pem` to `cacert.pem`. Please try this. I think the path is wrong.